# Sort Colors, can't seem to understand what is wrong

Tags: python

```
class Solution(object):
    def sortColors(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        l = []
        for i in range(3):
           for j in range(len(nums)):
               if nums[j] == i:
                   l.append(nums[j])
        nums = l
```

> [leetcode problem link](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-colors/)
>
> Can someone explain why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *"modify nums in-place"*. However,

```
nums = l
```

Does not mutate the list object previously referenced by nums! It just rebinds the *local* variable `nums`. The simple fix would be slice assignment:

```
nums[:] = l
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code using Bubble Sort Algorithm...

```
class Solution(object):
    def sortColors(self, nums):
        l = len(nums)
        for i in range(l-1):
           for j in range(i+1, l):
               if nums[i] > nums[j]: nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
```

Comment: Lol, for a sort problem that can actually be solved in linear time, you provide not even a typical log-linear, but a quadratic approach :)

Comment: I know, I have yet to learn sort algorithms, but thanks.